# How to fill a Devexpress.LookUpEdit with set values?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, devexpress

I have a Devexpress LookUpEdit that I want to fill with 2-3 values. For example "Value 1" (1) and "Value 2" (2). I want this name to be displayMember of the LookUpEdit and the number in brackets be the valueMember so that if I was given the number 1 I know to set the selected value of the LookUpEdit to "Value 1".

Comment: please elaborate  "want this name to be displayMember" what is "this" ? and also try to rephrase question, it would be difficult to understand; what exactly you needed. And FYI there is columns property for lu and as you bind your source to it, it will show up all the columns. have you checked that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a class with two properties, then bind a set of instances of it to the LookUpEdit.
You can then set the LookUpEdit's `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties.